# Получить доступ к элементу JSON

Tags: json, php, синтаксический-анализ

В ответ от VK API приходит JSON следующего вида:

```
{"response":{"count":122,"items":[{"id":8096,"from_id":1,"to_id":1,"date":1405239582,"post_type":"post","text":"#мысли #кличко","attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"id":333726218,"album_id":-7,"owner_id":1,"photo_75":"http:\/\/cs619128.vk.me\/v619128909\/10ac0\/nUaJUlWB_00.jpg","photo_130":"http:\/\/cs619128.vk.me\/v619128909\/10ac1\/Ed55JKWIvts.jpg","photo_604":"http:\/\/cs619128.vk.me\/v619128909\/10ac2\/kDxmpjunz9k.jpg","width":320,"height":480,"text":"","date":1405239581,"post_id":8096,"access_key":"89af80607767285ddd"}}],"comments":{"count":0},"likes":{"count":5},"reposts":{"count":1}}]}}
```

Нужно получть доступ к элементу "text":"", в этом json этот текст #мысли #кличко
Пытался обрабатывать через json_decode, а дальше получать как элемент массива, в итоге ничего не вышло. 
Помогите, а.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode('...', true);

echo $json["response"]["items"][0]["text"];
```